# why does itertools.count() consume an extra element when used with zip?

Tags: python, functional-programming

I was trying to use functools.partial with itertools.count, by currying zip with itertools.count():

```
g = functools.partial(zip, itertools.count())
```

When calling g with inputs like "abc", "ABC", I noticed that itertools.count() mysteriously "jumps".

I thought I should get the same result as directly using zip with itertools.count()? like:

```
>>> x=itertools.count();
>>> list(zip("abc",x))
[('a', 0), ('b', 1), ('c', 2)]
>>> list(zip("ABC",x))
[('A', 3), ('B', 4), ('C', 5)]
```

But instead, I get the following -- notice the starting index at the second call of g is 4 instead of 3:

```
>>> g = functools.partial(zip, itertools.count())
>>> list(g("abc"))
[(0, 'a'), (1, 'b'), (2, 'c')]
>>> list(g("ABC"))
[(4, 'A'), (5, 'B'), (6, 'C')]
```

Answer (score 7):

Note that you'd get the same result if your *original* code used arguments in the same order as your altered code:

```
>>> x = itertools.count()
>>> list(zip(x, "abc"))
[(0, 'a'), (1, 'b'), (2, 'c')]
>>> list(zip(x, "ABC"))
[(4, 'A'), (5, 'B'), (6, 'C')]
```

`zip()` tries its first argument first, then its second, then its third ... and stops when one of them is exhausted.

In the spelling just above, after `"abc"` is exhausted, it goes back to the first argument and gets `3` from `x`.  But its second argument is already exhausted, so `zip()` stops, and the `3` is silently lost.

Then it moves on to the second `zip()`, and starts by getting `4` from `x`.

`partial()` really has nothing to do with it.

Comment: I think I've already said this before... but... huge huge fan. Thank you for your service!

Answer (score 5):

It'll be easy to see why if you encapsulate `itertools.count()` inside a function:

```
def count():
    c = itertools.count()
    while True:
        v = next(c)
        print('yielding', v)
        yield v

g = functools.partial(zip, count())
list(g("abc"))
```

The output is

```
yielding 0
yielding 1
yielding 2
yielding 3
[(0, 'a'), (1, 'b'), (2, 'c')]
```

You'll see `zip` will evaluate the next argument from `count()` (so an extra value `3` is yielded) before it realises there isn't anything else left in the second iterable.

As an exercise, reverse the arguments and you'll see the evaluation is a little different.